# Yeoman is installed but no output is seen when attempt is made to run angular generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

No error appears when I run

```
yo angular appname
```

I have already installed yeoman and I am using ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstall the yeoman

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

Watch out for the last part of your installation.

[image]

Notice that for my output,

```
/usr/bin/yo -> /usr/lib/node_modules/yo/bin/yo
```

My solution is

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Inside the ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/lib/node_modules:$PATH
```

Basically add the paths where `yo` belongs to

Then execute the .bash_profile

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you can run the `yo angular appname`

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated nodejs to latest version (Mine is v0.10.33)

Open `/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js` 
and update `#!/usr/bin/env node` to `#!/usr/bin/env nodejs`